# rsync on Lion failing with Perl error

Tags: macos, rsync, perl

I'm trying to rsync a bunch of photos from one mac to another.

```
rsync -av /Users/billybobob/Pictures/ sarahsansskirt@192.168.1.4:/Volumes/Harddrive/Billybobob_Photos
```

I've got the keys correct because I can ssh from billybobob's computer into sarahsansskirt's computer.  I can also rsync to a freeNAS box I have with no issues.  However when I try to rsync to sarahsansskirt's computer I get

```
Can't locate local/lib.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /lib/perl5 /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.12 /Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.12 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.3 /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.12 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12 .).
```

`BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
Can't open perl script " -Mlocal::lib": No such file or directory`

I didn't think rsync had anything to do with Perl.

What am I doing wrong here?

BTW all that INC@ looks wrong, my Perl is basically broken on billybobob's computer.... but that shouldn't matter I think.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have specified `LocalCommand` option with some `perl` command in your `~/.ssh/config` for host `192.168.1.4`